# High CPU Usage and Heap Out of Memory Issue during npm run build in Laravel with Vue.js using Vite

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm, vite

I am facing a critical issue while working on a Laravel project with Vue.js using Vite as the build tool. When attempting to execute `npm run build`, the CPU usage spikes to 100%, and eventually, the process runs out of memory, leading to a system crash. How can I increase the allocated heap memory during the npm run build process to prevent CPU spikes and memory exhaustion?

**Environment:**

- Laravel: 9.52.16
- Vue.js: 3.3.9
- Vite: 5.0
- Node.js: 18.17.1
- npm: 9.6.7

**Problem:**

1. `High CPU Usage` : The CPU usage reaches 100% during the build process.
2. `Heap Out of Memory` : The build process exhausts the allocated heap memory, resulting in a system crash.

```
Error : FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving this issue. If there are specific configurations or optimizations to consider, please provide detailed steps to implement them. Thank you!

Comment: Where is this npm run build executed? Is this local? CI build runner? or production instance?

Comment: Yes It's in local machine
OS : windows 10 Pro

Comment: Thank you, Sky, for your suggestion. I appreciate it. Initially, running ```npm run build``` for our project went smoothly. However, as we updated requirements, file sizes increased, causing "npm run build" to slow down significantly, with CPU usage reaching 100%. This is the current scenario. Can you please advise on what I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is a known issue with a couple of packages.
So without the full list of the packages you have installed, we wont be able to determine what exactly causes it.
But hopefully this link will lead you in the right direction, since its possible to get past this error by playing around with the viteconfig.js file settings.

- https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2433#issuecomment-1482851550
- https://github.com/storybookjs/builder-vite/issues/409#issuecomment-1487699816

Comment: Thank you, Sky, for your suggestion. I appreciate it. Initially, running ```npm run build``` for our project went smoothly. However, as we updated requirements, file sizes increased, causing "npm run build" to slow down significantly, with CPU usage reaching 100%. This is the current scenario. Can you please advise on what I might have done wrong?

Comment: @VijaySolanki Is it possible for you to let us know what the most recent completed build size was, and if you tried implementing the solution that are on those posts, and if that solution changed anything?